# How to ssh AWS EC2 using CSV secret file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-iam

I have downloaded secret key in .csv format from my AWS IAM security settings. I want to use this secret key to ssh into aws ec2 instance. I tried using ssh -i   but got "key too open" error. So googled and found solution to disable inheritance on secret file (windows 10). Now I am having " format not supported" error. So I tried to convert CSV into .ppk/.pem format using MobaXterm but no success. 
Can anyone tell me how can I ssh in AWS EC2 by using secret key in .csv format, please?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are saying is that you have created an IAM user, downloaded credentials for that IAM user to a CSV file, and are now trying to SSH into an EC2 instance that you launched.

The credentials you downloaded are IAM credentials (access key and secret key). They are *not* SSH keys. When you launched the EC2 instance, you had an opportunity to supply a keypair. If you supplied a keypair *and* you have the corresponding private key (a PEM file), then you can SSH to the instance with that private key, for example:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ec2.pem hostname
```

The CSV of IAM credentials has nothing to do with SSH access in this case. You need the private key associated with the EC2 keypair. If you created the keypair using the EC2 console, then the PEM file was downloaded at that time.

The IAM credentials you have can be used to make AWS API calls to manage AWS resources. For example , to launch an EC2 instance, create an IAM role, or to delete a DynamoDB table. You can use them with SDKs and the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). These credentials are associated with an IAM user. If you usually log into the AWS Console to manage AWS resources, then you log in with a username and password but these are exchanged by the AWS backend for IAM credentials and those are used by the console when it calls the APIs on your behalf.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They are IAM credentials (access key and secret key). I am trying to connect to my organisation's bastion host. I haven't launched this instance and haven't got a corresponding private key. So what are these access key and secret key? What's their purpose and where can I use them?

Comment: To access your bastion host, you likely need the SSH private key unless you are using EC2 Instance Connect. I would talk to the person who set up the bastion for you to understand how to access it.

Comment: Oh! Got you now. Silly me, wasn't aware of this access key concept.  I spent an hour googling about it but didn't get clear idea so I was trying to convert secret access key .csv file into private key .pem file. ‍♀️‍♀️.

Comment: What to do if i want some developer to have access to my instance to deploy his project. But don't want to share my access key with them because if i  do that they will always be able to access the instance through ssh. @jarmod

Please help

Comment: @kbc add an additional SSH public key to the instance for use by that developer. See [Add or remove a public key on your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-key-pair.html). Bear in mind that this user will be able to leverage any IAM role that the instance was launched with so decide if that's acceptable before doing this. Alternatively, consider [instance connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html).

Comment: @jarmod Please can you help me with iam policy for access to specific instance with required permissions to deploy the developers app on my instance.

Comment: @kbc Hi, if you have a specific question that's suitable for Stack Overflow then please consider asking a brand new question. Comments on older questions aren't the best place to be doing this, especially as your question seems non-trivial and requires more context.

Answer (score 2):

What you downloaded is called access key which you will use to access AWS API, SDK and CLI. read more about it [aws IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) As far as login is concerned when you create an EC2 instance you are asked in the end to create a key which is of .pem format. Download it and change its permission to 600 or 400. That will resolve key too open error.

`chmod 600 <path/where/you downloaded/.pem key>`

Answer (score 0):

Jarmod is correct, you need to download the key/pair assigned to your EC2 instance, or go create a new key/pair, attach it to the ec2 instance and then use the .PEM to access by SSH the EC2 instance.
In Linux is easy, you just need to use this command to change the permission of the .pem file

```
chmod 400 filename.pem
```